# Как считать файл *.csv?

Tags: delphi, excel

команда

```
 Excel.Workbooks.Open[path];
```

открывает только файлы типа xls
а как открыть файл типа csv? это же тот же эксель по сути

Answer (score 1):

Открывает ваша строка и КСВ , 1000%.

Но удобней и лучше работать с КСВ как с обычным текстовым файлом, которым он по сути и является.

Answer (score 1):

Нажимаем запись макроса.
Жмем **Данные** - **Из файла** - выбираем нужный csv файл и указываем параметры импорта.
Останавливаем запись и открываем макрос для редактирования. Видим:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;C:\test.csv", Destination _
    :=Range("$A$1"))
    .CommandType = 0
    .Name = "test"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 1252
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Такой макрос у меня в Excel 2013 не воспроизводится выдавая ошибку (что не удивительно ибо мелкомягкие). Удаляем строку

```
.CommandType = 0
```

и все нормально воспроизводится.